# Example of convergent subsequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am going through the book "**Elementary real analysis** by Thomsan brukner" and i am stuck on question where we have to find an sequence that contains subsequences converges to every point in $[0, 1]$.

I tried many examples but couldn't find such sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.
You observe that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then you can fill the details.
Conclude that as $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set, you can write $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Note in case OP wasn't aware you can use Cantorian Diagonalization to order the points into a sequence

Comment: I think you don't need this, in a metric space sequential closure and closure are the same, so just from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$ you get that each real number has a sequence of rational converging to it.

Comment: I just meant in case the OP wasn't aware the rationals are countable and thus can be made into a sequence

Comment: You're right, sorry I was in a rush, I modify the answer, thanks mate @Alan ; I just took it for granted and in fact I have absolutely no idea why you would need cantor diagonal argument. I have studied this in my first analysis course, like 4 years ago lol